# What are the differences between Vector256.Create and Avx2.BroadcastScalarToVector functions?

Tags: c#, .net, simd, avx2

For example, I want to create a Vector256 variable with all elements initialized to a specified signed integer, supposedly my system supports Avx2. The .NET Document says broadcasting a scarlar with Avx2 uses `_mm256_broadcastd_epi32` and `_mm_broadcastd_epi32` instructions.

What instruction does `Vector256.Create` generate? Is it the same as the above?

```cs
int value = -1;
Vector256<int> v1 = Avx2.BroadcastScalarToVector256(&value);
Vector256<int> v2 = Vector256.Create(-1);
Debug.Assert(v1.Equals(v2)); // True
```

Comment: `_mm256_broadcastd_epi32` is a C intrinsic, not an assembly instruction.  Since C# doesn't compile to C and then to asm, that's poor documentation...  But presumably it will use a `vpbroadcastd` load from memory if possible, otherwise a `vmovd xmm0, ecx` / `vpbroadcastd ymm0, xmm0` if the value is hot in a register https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vpbroadcast.  (Or with AVX512VL, hopefully `vpbroadcastd ymm0, ecx`).  There is a way to see JITed asm from C#, and IIRC even an online compiler-explorer type site, but I forget what it is since I don't use C# myself.

Comment: But anyway, for a constant operand, I'd expect that like C compilers with `_mm256_set1_epi32( value )` it would normally load the value from a memory constant (ideally with a broadcast load), or for special cases like zero or -1 create it with `vpxor xmm0,xmm0,xmm0` to zero YMM0, or `vpcmpeqd ymm0,ymm0,ymm0` to set the register to all-ones with no false dependency on the old value.

Comment: Does `Vector256.Create` require a constant arg or something?

Comment: @PeterCordes sharplab [like this](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: @harold: Right thanks.  So it seems like `BroadcastScalarToVector256` really wants to be a broadcast-load and will store a variable first. `Vector256.Create(func_arg)` will `vmovd` / `vpbroadcastd ymm0, xmm0`.
 https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBDAzgWwB8ABAJgEYBYAKGIAYACY8gOgBEBLbAcwDsJcGDmFwBuGvSasASgFdeQ/DBYBJBVA69cwsRMbMWchRyWr1m7SJYANABxJx1CQGYmpBgGEGAbxoN/TK7yuNgAZjAMAGowYBjQpACsSAA8mhgAfAwAsuQAFACUPn4BJcQA7FExcVCJSCwesNgYMLlw5PmOJQC+xf69gQzBYRHRsfFJqQqZWaS5aQwAbtgANrIwhb7UJSUA9DvlDACCCwikLABCUBDYACZgeBgAyvfL2FAAKhCj1bW5AGRLVbrTrbfwHb7jOoNGBNFqAtYdfo9ahdIA=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL/DR: use `BroadcastScalarToVector256` when the source data is in memory, and `Vector256<int>.Create` in all other cases.

The documentation for `BroadcastScalarToVector256` says it compiles into this assembly: `VPBROADCASTD ymm, m32` This is what you want when the source scalar is in memory, but takes roundtrip to memory and back if the source data is a register. That roundtrip is slightly slower in terms of latency, even if the memory is on stack i.e. on L1D cache.

The documentation for `Vector256.Create( int )` doesn’t say what it compiles into, only says that it corresponds to `_mm256_set1_epi32` intrinsic in C++. This means JIT compiler is free to do whatever’s the most efficient.

If you call `Vector256<int>.Create( 0 )` it should compile into `vpxor ymm0, ymm0, ymm0` instruction, because that instruction is a fast way to zero out a vector.

When you call `Vector256<int>.Create( -1 )` it should compile into `vpcmpeqd ymm0, ymm0, ymm0` instruction or similar, again because the value is known to compiler, `vpcmpeqd` has no data dependencies, and does the job, fast.

When you pass a variable there, `Create` should compile into code like `vmovd xmm0, eax; vpbroadcastd ymm0, xmm0`, that’s two instructions, but still faster than roundtrip to memory and back.

Comment: *That roundtrip is relatively slow in terms of latency,* For the record, 2 cycles higher on Skylake than `vmovd xmm0, ecx` / `vpbroadcastd ymm0,xmm0`, for example, but avoids a shuffle uop because 32 and 64-bit broadcast loads are handled by the load port.  Occasionally worth considering for balancing throughput.  (test loop: NASM with vmovd eax, xmm0 to complete the round trip: https://godbolt.org/z/b1hxx3).  (`vpbroadcastb/w ymm, mem` loads have another 1 cycle latency, for a total of 3c worse than vmovd/vpbroadcastw.)

Comment: Store/reload is also 2 bytes larger code size with an `[rsp+disp8]` addressing mode, or worse with a REX prefix on the mov store.  Or same size with `[rsp]` or [rbp+disp8] and no REX

Comment: @PeterCordes OK, changed the wording. About my TL/DR recommendation, I think most code tends to bottleneck on load/store way more often than on shuffles. Another thing is context switches, if you’re really unlucky the OS may switch/resume the thread between the two instructions, in which case the data will move all the way to RAM.

Comment: Agreed that normally the ALU strategy is good.  But keep in mind that a lot of code that bottlenecks on load/store does so because of cache misses, not execution-unit throughput.  Also note that store-forwarding works (with constant latency) even if the store eventually misses in cache when it reaches the head of the store buffer and tries to commit to L1d cache.  (So it wouldn't stall the store-forwarding, but could eventually stall execution later when the store buffer fills waiting for this to commit; you don't want to use some random static / global var that's likely to be cold in cache.)

Comment: So yeah, it seems you should always use `Create`, as long as that can compile to a broadcast load when the operand does need to get loaded.  (not `mov` into integer reg / vmovd / vpbroadcastd ymm,xmm).  Not sure what the use-case for `BroadcastScalarToVector256` is; letting compilers decide what should be in registers when is part of the point of using compilers.  (Although to be fair, they're not perfect and sometimes it's nice to have a tool to stop them from making the wrong choice.)